# I am getting error while calculating the length of a string

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate the length of a string without using library function(for learning purpose). I am using the following code:

```
<?php 
$name = "Mohammad Umar";
$i=0;
while($name[$i] != ''){
    $i++;
}
echo $i++;
?>
```

But I am getting error like this:

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 13 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\form\test.php on line 4

I have already initialized $i, then why it is saying Uninitialized string offset? Is there a better way to calculate the length of a string without library function, please suggest me.

Comment: Why you need this if you have the `strlen` function?

Comment: What??? Why not strlen($name);?

Comment: Yes you are right. I was asked in an interview to calculate the length of a string without strlen. So I am basically asking for learning purpose.

Comment: Was it a an interview for a php job?

Comment: Because when you check `$name[13]` - you don't have such index.

Comment: They were testing my programmimg skills. Yes the interview was for PHP.

Comment: Thanks @u_mulder, is there any way to do this without using @  or having error in the code?

Comment: Str_split? Is that allowed? https://3v4l.org/OIDlt

Comment: In which version you are getting error : https://eval.in/847216

Comment: @user2486 any version. https://3v4l.org/m4n7K

Comment: I'm actually curious to why you would get such a question on a interview. It's nothing hard and there is no reason to not use strlen, is there?

Comment: @Andreas it shows creativity, the Welsh have a saying "there's more than one way to skin a cat" (I'm not advocating flaying cats) - it means there are many ways to solve the same problem. You could even solve this using a regular expression ;-) lol

Comment: @WeeZel I can understand the creativity. But why not a real question then? Say, print a string backwards without explode and each word still have to be "right". That is shows way more creativity in my opinion and is more of a question. But what do I know. I was in Wales one day a few years ago, didn't think about it then but now that you say it. I couldn't see any cats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without using the strlen function you could do this

```
$name = "Mohammad Umar";
$i=0;
while(isset($name[$i])){
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use str_split to split the string to an array and count it.

```
$name = "Mohammad Umar";
$arr = str_split ($name);
echo count($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/OIDlt#output

Another solution would be to do a regex `/.+/` and count the output array. But that is just plain S....
But it would work.

Comment: that was my alternative solution! +1 :-D

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use php's [strlen function](http://php.net/strlen)

```
<?php 
$name = "Mohammad Umar";
echo strlen($name);
?>
```

You are receiving the error because the code you've written checks for `$name[13]` this part however does not exist. you can go from `[0]` to `[12]`.

**edit**

Just read you can't use `strlen`

then why not check if it exists

```
while(isset($name[$i]){
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Read the comments above,

Comment: `I am trying to calculate the length of a string without using library function(for lerning purpose)`

Answer (score 1):

2 more ways: both functions use `substr()`, the first utilises a `while()` loop and the second is recursive

```
function stringLen1($string)
{
    $result = 0;
    while ($string != '') { // note: loose typing
        $string = substr($string,1);
        $result++;
    }
    return $result;
}

function stringLen2($string)
{
    if ($string == '') { // note: loose typing
        $result = 0;
    } else {
        $result = stringLen2(substr($string,1)) + 1;
    }
    return $result;
}

$name = "Mohammad Umar";
echo stringLen1($name)."<br />\n";

echo stringLen2($name)."<br />\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop can also work for this.

```
for ($i = 0; isset($name[$i]); $i++);

echo $i;
```

To address your question:

> "I have already initialized $i, then why it is saying Uninitialized string offset?"

It doesn't mean that the variable `$i` is uninitialized. It means that the value of `$i` (13) is an uninitialized offset of `$name`.